# issue windows 8.1 all apps minimize automatically

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, minimize

My operating system is Windows 8.1. When i  open an application, it is automatically minimizing .I can't view any of the application. How to fix it. i have try to edit Gpedit.msc. But it is not opening.